# Why are int32s/int64s slower than ints?

Tags: ocaml

I've just read this in the reference doc of the Int32 module:

> Performance notice: values of type int32 occupy more memory space than
>   values of type int, and arithmetic operations on int32 are generally
>   slower than those on int. Use int32 only when the application requires
>   exact 32-bit arithmetic.

Why int32s happen to be generally slower than ints? Is it because they are boxed or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it because they are boxed or something?

Yes.